# How to pass package.json version as ENV variable in GitHub action?

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

I have [this GitHub action](https://github.com/termsurf/chocolatey-task/blob/c8d6ad92738bcc8d2a7bc3f3fb9e624ff01be602/.github/workflows/build.yaml#L23-L40):

```
on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: windows-2022
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Cache Tools
        uses: actions/cache@v3.0.11
        with:
          path: tools
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-cache
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20.10.x
      - name: Choco pack
        run: choco pack task.nuspec
      - name: LS
        run: dir .
      - name: Set PACKAGE_VERSION
        id: version
        run: echo "PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      - name: Choco install
        env:
          PACKAGE_VERSION: ${{ steps.version.outputs.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
        run:
          choco install task.${{ steps.version.outputs.PACKAGE_VERSION }}.nupkg
      - name: Choco set api key
        env:
          CHOCOLATEY_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.CHOCOLATEY_API_KEY }}
        run:
          choco apikey --key $CHOCOLATEY_API_KEY --source https://push.chocolatey.org/
      - name: Choco publish
        env:
          PACKAGE_VERSION: ${{ steps.version.outputs.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
        run:
          choco push task.${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}.nupkg --source https://push.chocolatey.org/
```

At the `Choco install` step, it is showing this in the logs:

```
Run choco install task..nupkg
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Package name cannot point directly to a local, or remote file. Please use the --source argument and point it to a local file directory, UNC directory path or a NuGet feed instead.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

So with `task..nupkg` it is clearly not passing the env variable. My repo is [here](https://github.com/termsurf/chocolatey-task), and the `package.json` is at the top-level of the project with:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.2",
  ...
}
```

I've tried at least these 3 ways if not way more to get it to pass it to it properly:

```
# this
- name: Choco install
  env:
    PACKAGE_VERSION: ${{ steps.version.outputs.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
  run:
    choco install task.${{ steps.version.outputs.PACKAGE_VERSION }}.nupkg
# or this
- name: Choco install
  env:
    PACKAGE_VERSION: ${{ steps.version.outputs.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
  run:
    choco install task.$PACKAGE_VERSION.nupkg
    # results in literal 'Run choco install task.$PACKAGE_VERSION.nupkg' error
# or this
- name: Choco install
  env:
    PACKAGE_VERSION: ${{ steps.version.outputs.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
  run:
    choco install task.${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}.nupkg
    # results in 'Run choco install task..nupkg' error
```

Locally, running the `node` command gives this:

```
$ echo "PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")"
PACKAGE_VERSION=0.0.2
```

So that looks like it's working.

What am I missing? I am using the [`GITHUB_OUTPUT`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-masking-a-generated-output-within-a-single-job) feature, but if there is a better way please let me know.

Basically I am just trying to build the package with the correct version, so if there is a better way let me know, perhaps with the `choco` command.

Comment: Your runner is `windows-2022` (with default shell as the PowerShell) but your syntax under `run` sections is that of Bash. [`PACKAGE_VERSION`](https://github.com/termsurf/chocolatey-task/actions/runs/7620280789/job/20754749660#step:8:5) is not being set properly here. Use `shell: bash` or use the Liinux based runner e.g. `ubuntu-latest`.

Answer (score 0):

@Azeem was right (I figured out contemporaneously), I am in PowerShell, and this was using Bash. So I changed it and it works.

```
- name: Set ENV vars
  id: version
  run: |
    echo "PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat choco.json | jq -r '.version')" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
- name: Choco publish
  env:
    CHOCOLATEY_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.MY_KEY }}
  run:
    cd load/choco && choco push --key $env:MY_KEY task.${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}.nupkg --source
    https://push.chocolatey.org/
```

Specifically using `$env:GITHUB_ENV` and the like, or `${{ env.X }}`, now that I *set* the env vars correctly.